# Get records in a date range

Tags: mysql

Table 1:

```
ID | FOO_ID | BAR|  START_DATE | END_DATE
1  |   343  | 3 | 11-02-2014 | 2-03-2016
```

Table 2:

```
ID | FOO_ID | BAR | MONTH | CALCULATION A 
1  |  343   |  3  |   1   |      .98772 
2  |  343   |  3  |   2   |      .92422
3  |  343   |  3  |   3   |      .89223
4  |  343   |  3  |   4   |      .79002 
5  |  343   |  3  |   5   |     1.00182 
6  |  343   |  3  |   6   |      .97235 
7  |  343   |  3  |   7   |      .98674 
8  |  343   |  3  |   8   |      .99986  
9  |  343   |  3  |   9   |      .78942  
10 |  343   |  3  |  10   |      .67932 
11 |  343   |  3  |  11   |      .95282
12 |  343   |  3  |  12   |      .94828
```

Desired Outcome:

```
FOO ID | BAR | MONTH | CALCULATION A
343    |  3  | 11    |  .95282 
343    |  3  | 12    |  .94828
343    |  3  |  1    |  .98772 
343    |  3  |  2    |  .92422
343    |  3  |  3    |  .89223
343    |  3  |  4    |  .79002 
343    |  3  |  5    |  1.00182 
343    |  3  |  6    |  .97235 
343    |  3  |  7    |  .98674
343    |  3  |  8    |  .99986  
343    |  3  |  9    |  .78942 
343    |  3  |  10   |  .67932 
343    |  3  |  11   |  .95282
343    |  3  |  12   |  .94828 
343    |  3  |  1    |  .98772 
343    |  3  |  2    |  .92422
```

What I am trying to do here is create the "desired outcome" table so that i can do a sum of column 'calculation a' in table 2 over each row in table 1, from the start date (11/2014 in the example), to the end date(2/2016) in the example. The calculations in table 2 only have a month column.  I must sum over month 1, month 2, month 11 and month 12 twice in this example.

```
SUM(Calculation A)
group foo_id, bar
```

Where I am having trouble is having to sum over month 1, month 2, month 11, and month 12 twice, and getting it to appear twice in the "desired result table. I need help with this query to create the "desired table" from table 1 and table 2 in MySQL.

Comment: Those aren't mysql dates, so what you want is not (easily) possible. Since they're not mysql dates, you can't directly use any of the built-in mysql date/time processinig capabilities, and your query will end up being hugely ugly.

Comment: They are mysql dates in the actual table, proceed as if that is a date column in table 1.  The year is first in the table.

Comment: Seems like your desired result is to apply calculation values to months where they didn't actually take place.  What value is there in reading a report with made up values like that?

Comment: Look, this is what the client wants. I can't really change this aspect of the program.   I still have to get MySQL to do this calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The output should be obtained so

```
select FOO_ID, BAR,  MONTH,  `CALCULATION A`
from table 2
order by field(month , 11, 12, 1, 2, 3,4, 5,6 ,7 8,9, 10)
```